# My nose is always dry from inside and therefore very irritating. How to keep it moistened?

Tags: personal-care

It is a daily problem. Please guide about what can I do to keep my nose moist from inside most of the time.

Comment: Do you know *why* it is dry? Maybe some work place, dry weather?

Comment: I don't know your circumstances, but this could be an indication that you are not drinking enough water.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem and dab a Q tip in olive oil or avocado oil and rub it around the interior bases of my nostrils every morning, and then let it sit for a good 3-4 hours before blowing my nose. It has proven very effective.

Answer (score 4):

I have always just used a little Vaseline on the inside of my nose.

Comment: I agree. My mom has a deviated septum, and she applies Vaseline with a Q-tip every day.

Answer (score 2):

Coconut oil is also a very effective moisturizer for a dry nose as is baby oil. I used to use Vaseline but after reading about the possibility of contracting pneumonia as a result (because it's a petroleum product), I switched to coconut oil and/or baby oil...or any vegetable-based oil (olive, avocado, etc) to relieve nasal dryness.  I apply a bit (doesn't take much) each evening and morning and no longer have problems with nose bleeds which were beginning to be an on-going problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

**You need:**

-A large bowl

-A towel

-Hot water

**Directions**

Bring several cups of water to boil and then pour into your bowl. Place your face over the bowl (not too close though, as the steam can be quite hot) and drape a towel over your head and the bowl to trap the steam. Breathe deeply for 5-10 minutes, and then follow up 15 minutes later with an application of coconut oil. If you don’t feel like making up a bowl of hot water just for your nose, even inhaling the steam from a cup of tea or taking a hot shower can really help.

Comment: this is a natural way to moisturize the skin. specially if you use coconut oil with a cotton swab, it will repair your skin: It also doesn’t glob like petroleum jelly does, so the risk of a big chunk getting sucked up isn’t there

Answer (score 1):

Not much of a lifehack, but you could just opt for a nasal spray like:

[http://www.amazon.com/Ayr-Saline-Nasal-Soothing-Ounce/dp/B0010NSC1U?ie=UTF8&keywords=nose%20moisture&qid=1461915929&ref_=sr_1_1_a_it&sr=8-1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0010NSC1U)

Answer (score 1):

Any nasal spray containing soothing oil will do wonders. Some products use aloe, others use sesame oil.

People where I live (VERY arid Namibia) put a small dab of petroleum jelly on the tip of one of their fingers and stick it in their nose and try and spread it evenly. This also works very well. Having to wash you hands all the time, is a nuisance though.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting a humidifier nearby to where you spend a lot of your day, and see if the moister air helps. Also be sure to drink plenty of water/other liquids throughout the day.

Answer (score 1):

Some people have recommended Nasal sprays. However, that could potentially have a longterm impact, such as chemical dependency, on your nose if you useful often (e.g many times per day).

I would recommend buying a humidifier if you can place one in your room. Or, if not, another trick is place bowl of water or a wet towel nearby as you work or sleep. It will add moisture to the air as the water evaporates from your bowl or towel. Therefore, keeping the air moist and preventing your nose from getting too dry.

Answer (score 1):

No substance containing any kind of oil is good for a dry nose. It can get into your lungs and cause an abscess. You should only use water based moisturizers or sterilized or distilled water which is what most commercial products are made from. read the medical literature on the internet. Don't depend on unqualified opinions.

Answer (score 1):

A humidifier in your bedroom while you sleep is a great option, as well as Secaris nasal gel.

Comment: This adds nothing to an existing answer.